# MongoDB - Unwind array using aggregation and remove duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I am unwinding an array using MongoDB aggregation framework and the array has duplicates and I   need to ignore those duplicates while doing a grouping further.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: HI andrewrk can you please share schema for above Question and answer

Answer (score 53):

you can use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) to do this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$data' },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id', data: { $addToSet: '$data' } } }
]);
```

It's hard to give you more specific answer without seeing your actual query.

Comment: i thought of that. I can unwind, addtoset and do unwind again. But wanted to see if i can a different way. Thanks.

Comment: you can just group by id and array element (without add to set), can't say more without your query

Answer (score 28):

You have to use $addToSet, but at first you have to group by _id, because if you don't you'll get an element per item in the list.

Imagine a collection posts with documents like this:

```
{
     body: "Lorem Ipsum...", 
     tags: ["stuff", "lorem", "lorem"],
     author: "Enrique Coslado"
}
```

Imagine you want to calculate the most usual tag per author. You'd make an aggregate query like that:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        author: "$author", 
        tags: "$tags", 
        post_id: "$_id"
    }}, 

    {$unwind: "$tags"}, 

    {$group: {
        _id: "$post_id", 
        author: {$first: "$author"}, 
        tags: {$addToSet: "$tags"}
    }}, 

    {$unwind: "$tags"},

    {$group: {
        _id: {
            author: "$author",
            tags: "$tags"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])
```

That way you'll get documents like this:

```
{
     _id: {
         author: "Enrique Coslado", 
         tags: "lorem"
     },
     count: 1
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I would just add a `{$sort: {count : -1}}` as last stage of the pipeline in order to sort.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers are correct, but the procedure of doing `$unwind -> $group -> $unwind` could be simplified.
You could use `$addFields` + `$reduce` to pass to the pipeline the filtered array which already contains unique entries and then `$unwind` only once.

Example document:

```
{
     body: "Lorem Ipsum...", 
     tags: [{title: 'test1'}, {title: 'test2'}, {title: 'test1'}, ],
     author: "First Last name"
}
```

Query:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {
        "uniqueTag": {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$tags",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", ["$$this.title"]]}
            }
        }
    }}, 

    {$unwind: "$uniqueTag"}, 

    {$group: {
        _id: {
            author: "$author",
            tags: "$uniqueTag"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])
```

Comment: This answers the question I was going to ask about how to remove duplicate array entries in a document field. I knew I could use $unwind/$addToSet but it just feels that the step would duplicate so much data it's going to be slower than just getting everything and doing the aggregation in code.

Comment: This is an incredibly expensive operation.