# removing duplicate array values from mongodb

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

In mongodb I have collection where arrays has duplicate entries like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57cf3cdd5f20a3b0ba009777"),
    "Chat": 6,
    "string": [
        "1348157031 Riyadh",
        " 548275320 Mohammad Sumon",
        " 1348157031 Riyadh",
        " 548275320 Mohammad Sumon",
        " 1348157031 Riyadh",
        " 1348157031 Riyadh"
    ]
}
```

I need to remove duplicate arrays and keep only unique array values like below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57cf3cdd5f20a3b0ba009777"),
    "Chat": 6,
    "string": [
        "1348157031 Riyadh",
        " 548275320 Mohammad Sumon",
    ]
}
```

what would be the best way to do this

thanks

Comment: Do you want to modify existing document or want to apply this to new documents only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate entries from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862255/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-an-array)

Comment: Yes I do want to modify existing document

Comment: I understand this is kind of duplicate but would be grateful if anyone could help

Comment: You probably need to do this client side like this (which is listed in the duplicate link)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405331/how-to-remove-duplicate-record-in-mongodb-by-mapreduce

Comment: above link try to remove record but I just need to remove duplicate list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$string'},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id', 
            string: {
                $addToSet: '$string'
            }, 
            Chat: {
                $first: '$Chat'
            }
        }
    }
    ]);
```

O/P:
here you are getting 2 "1348157031 Riyadh" because there is an extra space which defines itself as an different entity.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cf3cdd5f20a3b0ba009777"),
    "string" : [ 
        " 1348157031 Riyadh", 
        " 548275320 Mohammad Sumon", 
        "1348157031 Riyadh"
    ],
    "Chat" : 6
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shantanu, can I use any code to trim space from first element from this array.

Comment: If its bymistake then i would suggest you to modify it directly in db,
and always trim and save at the client side from the next time

Comment: @ Shantany I am able to aggregate but how to permanently delete duplicate element from db

Comment: Follow the link this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804404/mongodb-unwind-array-using-aggregation-and-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Mongo 3.4+ has [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) aggregation stage, which allows you to avoid explicitly listing all the other fields to keep:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {"$addFields": {
        "string": {"$setUnion": ["$string", []]}
    }}
])
```

Just for reference, here is another (more lengthy) way that uses [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and also doesn't require listing all possible fields:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': {
        'path': '$string',
        // output the document even if its list of books is empty
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'string': {'$addToSet': '$string'},
        // arbitrary name that doesn't exist on any document
        '_other_fields': {'$first': '$$ROOT'},
    }},
    {
      // the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field. (c) docs
      // so the new deduped array value will be used
      '$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': {'$mergeObjects': ['$_other_fields', "$$ROOT"]}}
    },
    {'$project': {'_other_fields': 0}}
])
```